# Java method that returns interface type

Tags: java

As I was reading about java interface, I came across the following example. I know how to implement an interface. But returning interface type in a method is something new to me. Could someone help me to understand this example? Will the methods in the "Animal" interface be implemented in the "categorizeAnimals" method? If yes, the "animals" array will be passed into all the interface methods in the "categorizeAnimals" method?

```
public class Wild {

  public static interface Animal {
      public List<String> getInvertebrates();
      public List<String> getFishes();
      public List<String> getAmphibians();
      public List<String> getReptiles();
  }


  public static Animal categorizeAnimals(String[] animals) {
    .......
    .......
    .......
    return null;
  }
}
```

Appreciate your reply, Thanks much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699427/what-does-it-mean-for-a-function-to-return-an-interface

Comment: I'm not clear on what the question is. Returning an implementation of an interface is very, very common.

Comment: @ramanrayat, thanks for that link. Guys, I am new to this interface concept. Trying to understand. So what I asked may sound silly.

Comment: *I know how to implement an interface.* Good. You know the difficult part. When a method returns an interface it is guaranteed that it returns something that implements that interface.

Comment: if you returning any interface into the return type make sure whatever instance u returning that has to have interface implemented.

Comment: Thanks all for helping me to understand this. You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simple solution is that if you have put any interface into the any of the method then then what ever class instance you are returning that class has to have that interface implemented.

```
public class ImplementedClass implements Interfacename {

    @Override
    public void sayhi(String hello) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void sayhello() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public Interfacename sayhello1() {
        System.out.println("returning new intance of class which is implementing that interface");
        return new ImplementedClass();
    }
}
```

interface is

```
public interface Interfacename {
    public void sayhi(String hello);

    public void sayhello();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A reference to an interface can represent a value of any type that implements that interface, and only of those types.

As others have said, the fragment you're showing us seems a bit incoherent, so I'm not going to try to explain it -- let's try this instead:

If we say `Bear`, `Trout`, and `Mosquito` are the subclasses of `Animal`, a function which returns `Animal` could return an instance of any of those types -- just as a function which takes an `Animal` as a parameter could accept instances of any of those via that parameter.

(This is actually a bad example -- Bear, Trout, and Mosquito are more likely to be instances, with the types being things like Mammal, Fish, and Insect -- but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

in the body of `categorizeAnimals` method your return type should be an instance of a class which has been implemented `Animal` interface